# MVC3 Exception Handling and customErrors issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I am trying the MVC3 exception handling, and came with following test code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        throw new ArgumentException();
        return View();
    }
}
```

My controller forces to throw exception, and in my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorHandler/Index">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/NotFound"></error>
</customErrors>
```

I have created another controller to server ErrorHandler/Index and ErrorHandler/NotFound request already.

With my testing, I can see the 404 code could be captured but 500 code has been ignore totally.

Anything wrong with my code?

Thanks
Hardy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following line:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

from the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method in your `Global.asax`.